# How access value of nested html element with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nested, element

I have this piece of code:

```
   <td class="fieldValue " id="Contacts_detailView_fieldValue_leadsource" >
     <span class="value" data-field-type="picklist" >
      <span >Partner</span>
     </span>
   </td>
```

how do i access the value "Partner"?
Thank you

Comment: document.querySelector(".value span").textContent;

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but in the code I have many `<span>` with the same class, so I have to refer to the `<td>` which has unique id, how do i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the parent element and from there go to the child to get the innerHtml

```
const value = document.querySelector(".value")
const partner = value.children; 

// partner[0] is for taking the first element 
// and then .innerHTML is for the content inside
console.log(partner[0].innerHTML)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in the code I have many `<span>` with the same class, so I have to refer to the `<td>` which has unique id, how do i do?

Comment: Just simply use document.querySelector("#id-of-your-td")

Answer (score 0):

I finally adopted this solution:

```
function textSpan(id){
    const collection = document.getElementById(id);
    const value = collection.children;
    const final = value[0].children[0].innerText;
    return final;
}console.log(textSpan('Contacts_detailView_fieldValue_leadsource'));
```

Thank you all for the suggestions!